# SSL handshake failed SVN (no SSL certificate)

Tags: svn, ssl, cornerstone

I'm using conerstone on a mac. I get the following error when trying to connect the repo:

```
Description : Unable to contact the repository at    https://users@repoURL.com because an SSL session could not be established.
Suggestion : This Mac was unable to present a valid certificate or the server's certificate was rejected as invalid.
Error : V4SSLHandshakeFailureError
Exception : ZSVNSSLHandshakeFailureException
Description : Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://users@repoURL.com'
 Status : 175002
Description : OPTIONS of 'https://users@repoURL.com': SSL handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856 (https://users@repoURL.com)
 Status : 175002
```

So yes, SSL auth failed because there is **NO** SSL certificate installed. So great. How do I tell cornerstone (or SVN) that I trust this location manually?

Comment: No SSL certificate? So why do you use HTTPS to access the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to upgrade to the newer Subversion client (which is built against newer OpenSSL version). Verify that the URL you enter matches the hostname and the certificate's common name, as well.

Comment: Cornerstone is up to date. Or are you saying I need to manually update SVN on my machine?

hostname and certificates common name do not match. Thank you there.

And just because there is not SSL Cert doesn't mean we won't want to trasnfer data over https, no?

Comment: Common name not matching the URL turned out to be the issue.

Comment: Upgrading from macOS Cornerstone version 2.x to 4.x, fixed it for me after server got new SSL certificate configuration.